# asp.net form Authentication and some features that are visiable for all

Tags: asp.net

i want to implement a website where some features are accessable by all visitors but some require logging in !! what's the easiest way to implement this in ASP.net ?!

Comment: This is a very broad question and already answered multiple times here. Search for "ASP.Net authentication" to find questions with answers on allowing users to login. Then search for "ASP.Net authorization" to find questions with answers to how to limit what different types of users have access to. ASP.Net has built in support for both through the Membership and Roles providers.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) is a series of articles on how to do this.